# How to fetch record from an array if we have concept of array index, using array_column function?

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I have an array of cryptocoin rates.
The array is looking as:

```
$array = Array ( [0] => Array ( [code] => BTC [name] => Bitcoin [rate] => 1 )
 [1] => Array ( [code] => BCH [name] => Bitcoin Cash [rate] => 7.06364 )
 [2] => Array ( [code] => USD [name] => US Dollar [rate] => 8185.84 ) )
```

I get results using `$array[1]['rate'];`

But i want to get result by [code] .

Like `$array['USD']['rate']`

Like `$array['BCH']['rate']`

How i can get the **rate** using currency code e.g **USD**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are there dictionaries in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6490482/are-there-dictionaries-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

You can loop the array and build a new associative array to use in the rest of the project.

```
$array = Array( 0 => Array( "code" => "BTC", "name" => "Bitcoin", "rate" => 1 ),
 "1" => Array ( "code" => "BCH", "name" => "Bitcoin Cash", "rate" => 7.06364 ),
 "2" => Array ( "code" => "USD", "name" => "US Dollar", "rate" => 8185.84 ) );

 foreach($array as $val){
     $rates[$val["code"]] = $val;
 }

 echo $rates['USD']['rate']; // 8185.84
```

https://3v4l.org/0qs0n

---

Another option is to use array_column and array_combine to do it without loops.

```
$array = Array( 0 => Array( "code" => "BTC", "name" => "Bitcoin", "rate" => 1 ),
 "1" => Array ( "code" => "BCH", "name" => "Bitcoin Cash", "rate" => 7.06364 ),
 "2" => Array ( "code" => "USD", "name" => "US Dollar", "rate" => 8185.84 ) );

 $keys = array_column($array, "code");
 $rates = array_combine($keys, $array);

 echo $rates['USD']['rate'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [array_reduce](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) and set the key to the value of `code` in the callback function:

```
$array = array_reduce($array, function($carry, $item) {
    $carry[$item["code"]] = $item;
    return $carry;
});

echo $array["USD"]["rate"]; //8185.84
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/Al03k)