# PHP how to arrays for

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, unique

I have two arrays like this:

```
$path = array("Login", "Register");
$list = array("Admin", "Customers", "Guest");

for ($i=0, $i<=count($path), $i++, $k=0; $k<=count($list); $k++) {
    echo "Var " . $path[$i] . " is " . $list[$k] . "\n";
}
```

Output :

```
Var Register is Admin
Var Register is Customers
Var Register is Guest
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined offset: 3 in <b>[...][...]</b> on line <b>6</b><br />
Var Register is
```

I need Output this

```
Var Login is Admin
Var Login is Customers
Var Login is Guest
Var Register is Admin
Var Register is Customers
Var Register is Guest
```

Any have solution?

Comment: @RolandStarke can write the code ?

Comment: @alifiaavirista - Have you thought about using a [dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6490482/are-there-dictionaries-in-php)?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com.
Please take some time to read the [help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and
["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).
Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$path = array("Login", "Register");
$list = array("Admin", "Customers", "Guest");

for ($i=0; $i<count($path); $i++) {
    for($j=0;$j<count($list);$j++){
       echo "Var " . $path[$i] . " is " . $list[$k] . "\n";
    }
}
```

**Hope this will help you**

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a second foreach.

```
<?php
$path = array("Login", "Register");
$list = array("Admin", "Customers", "Guest");

foreach ($path as $p) {
    foreach ($list as $l) { 
        echo "Var " . $p . " is " . $l . "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: and reference is used why?

Comment: I removed reference

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to walk over array you can use `foreach` loop:

```
foreach ($path as $p) {
    $row = 'Var ' . $p . ' is ';
    foreach ($list as $l) {
        echo $row . $l . "\n";
    }
}
```

where first loop walks through vars and then inner loop uses every var for every list item

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$path = array("Login", "Register");
$list = array("Admin", "Customers", "Guest");

foreach ($path as $row) {
    foreach ($list as $data) {
        echo "Var " . $row . " is " . $data . "\n";
        echo '<br />';
    }
}
```

You just need a double foreach loop to parse the arrays.

The output is :

```
Var Login is Admin 
Var Login is Customers 
Var Login is Guest 
Var Register is Admin 
Var Register is Customers 
Var Register is Guest
```